# remote lookup on a remote client in Java RMI

Tags: java, localhost, rmi

As long as I run multiple clients on my local host everything works just fine. Problems arise when I start a client on a different host.

For instance, at some point during execution methods on the server are invoked with localhost as the destination, meaning that the server suddenly forgets about the remote client's IP address. How is that possible?

Also, remote lookup performed by the server takes forever to complete. Could it be my router denying access to it? Or is the server desperately trying to use different paths to get to the remote host?

Comment: What do you mean by server forgets client's IP? Let client starts communicate with server and server should create a list or persist those IP data some where and use it for further communication.

Comment: how do you make the lookup from the client side? how do you create the registry on the server side? From your app or you start it before? and how do you bind your objects in the registry? Some code or a stack trace will be great. As far as the lookup time is concerned afaik it is different on windows and unix OSs. On unix it takes longer. You can change the value by extending the RMISocketFactory class. There are some tutorials how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servers don't need to perform remote lookups. Clients do that.

If your clients are throwing ConnectExceptions indicating they are trying to connect to 'localhost' when they shouldn't be, see item A.1 of the [RMI FAQ](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html).